# angular2 fetched img not rendering

Tags: angular

my problem is, I´m uploading multiple images by ng2-file-upload in frontend with angular2 and multer in backend.
After the files are uploaded, the response object is saved in my "product" object to make clear to which product the images belong to.
This works fine and Im getting as response for example this:

```html
destination
:
"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/server/routes/../uploads"
encoding
:
"7bit"
fieldname
:
"productImage"
filename
:
"1503791892150_BWbHb5s.jpg"
mimetype
:
"image/jpeg"
originalname
:
"BWbHb5s.jpg"
path
:
"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ngStore/server/uploads/1503791892150_BWbHb5s.jpg"
size
:
667147
```

now when i want angular2 to render this image, it is not shown..
of course on init Im fetching the data.
I have a category object, which has a nested products object and this has also nested images objects, whith the responses of multer.

however i want to display the image by setting the src attribute to the path field of the image object but it is not displaying me the image, allthough i can see the path is correct...

```html
<img [attr.src]="prod.images[0].path" height="500" width="500">
```

can anyone help me please?

Comment: are you available in teamviewer? need debugging

Comment: yes i am. that would be nice how can i get in contact with you for tv data?

Comment: nobody can help?

Comment: debuggin using TV , great to hear @Aravind , keep it up

Comment: Thanks man.  The issue is because he is trying to access file path using angular app which will log insecure error

Comment: okay so he needs to make changes in backend side to make it correct path i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using safe navigation operator like this

```
<img [attr.src]="prod?.images[0]?.path" height="500" width="500">
```

Sometimes Image being loaded after some time of View loading so in that case this will work.

Comment: not working. Aravind debugged a bit my code and we found out that it is a security issue. my problem is i get a local path from my node server as response which im using and as result i get no image.. SO maybe  the better question is how can i get the remote path from multer? or is there any way to bypass security mechanism of angular?

Comment: yup, nice , so that mean you need to make changes in the backend side.